How to update nested object state in react , initialize with {} , then json data that I got from api
How to update nested object state in react , initialize with {} , then json data that I got from api.
Why this code is not working:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
const App = () => {
  const [testData, setTestData] = useState({});
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/recommendations");
        const result = await response.json(); 
        setTestData(result);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Found error while fetching data: ${err}`);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); 


  useEffect(() => {

    setTestData(prevState => {
      const updatedData = {
        ...prevState,
        recommendation: {
          ...prevState.recommendation,
          rules: prevState.recommendation.rules.map(rule => {
            if (rule.scenario_name === "data_rule") {
              return {
                ...rule,
                passwhen: {
                  ...rule.passwhen,
                  STATE: "INDIA"
                }
              };
            }
            return rule;
          })
        }
      };
      return updatedData;
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data", testData);
  }, [testData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(testData, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;



I'm working on a React application where I need to update the state of a nested object. Initially, my state is set to an empty object {}. I fetch JSON data from an API that should populate this nested state.
After fetching the data, I want to update specific keys within this nested object. However, I'm facing issues with my approach. In the provided example, the state isn't being initialized properly, leading to errors when attempting to update nested properties.
How should I properly initialize and update my nested object state with the fetched JSON data, ensuring that the state update is handled correctly and immutably?
Api Data
{
    "recommendation": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "scenario_name": "duplicate_check",
                "scenario_target_query": "SELECT * FROM beat2020.orders_info",
                "columns": [
                    "ORDERNO"
                ],
                "tgt_lvl_key": [
                    "ORDERNO"
                ],
                "idx": 0
            },
            {
                "scenario_name": "null_check",
                "scenario_target_query": "SELECT ORDERNO, QUANTITY_ORDERED, PRICE_EACH, SALES_PRICE, ORDERDATE, STATUS FROM beat2020.orders_info",
                "columns": [
                    "ORDERNO",
                    "QUANTITY_ORDERED",
                    "PRICE_EACH",
                    "SALES_PRICE",
                    "ORDERDATE",
                    "STATUS"
                ],
                "idx": 1
            },
            {
                "scenario_name": "data_validation",
                "scenario_source_query": "SELECT ORDERNUMBER, QUANTITYORDERED, PRICEEACH, ORDERLINENUMBER, SALES, FORMAT(ORDERDATE, 'MM-DD'), CASE WHEN STATUS IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, QTR_ID, MONTH_ID, YEAR_ID, PRODUCTLINE, MSRP, PRODUCTCODE, CUSTOMERNAME, PHONE, ADDRESSLINE1, ADDRESSLINE2, CITY, IF(STATE IS NULL, 'US', STATE), POSTALCODE, COUNTRY, TERRITORY FROM beat2020.orders",
                "scenario_target_query": "SELECT ORDERNO, QUANTITY_ORDERED, PRICE_EACH, ORDERLINENO, SALES_PRICE, ORDERDATE, STATUS, QTR_ID, MONTH_ID, YEAR_ID, PRODUCTLINE, MSRP, PRODUCTCODE, CUSTOMERNAME, PHONE, ADDRESSLINE1, ADDRESSLINE2, CITY, STATE, POSTALCODE, COUNTRY, TERRITORY FROM beat2020.orders_info",
                "columns": [
                    "ORDERNUMBER",
                    "QUANTITYORDERED",
                    "PRICEEACH",
                    "ORDERLINENUMBER",
                    "SALES",
                    "ORDERDATE",
                    "STATUS",
                    "QTR_ID",
                    "MONTH_ID",
                    "YEAR_ID",
                    "PRODUCTLINE",
                    "MSRP",
                    "PRODUCTCODE",
                    "CUSTOMERNAME",
                    "PHONE",
                    "ADDRESSLINE1",
                    "ADDRESSLINE2",
                    "CITY",
                    "STATE",
                    "POSTALCODE",
                    "COUNTRY",
                    "TERRITORY"
                ],
                "src_lvl_key": [
                    "ORDERNUMBER"
                ],
                "tgt_lvl_key": [
                    "ORDERNO"
                ],
                "idx": 2
            },
            {
                "scenario_name": "data_rule",
                "scenario_target_query": "SELECT * FROM beat2020.orders_info",
                "passwhen": {
                    "ORDERDATE": "DATE MM-DD",
                    "STATUS": "IN 1,2",
                    "STATE": "IN US"
                },
                "idx": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}


What exactly is the specific issue you face? Are you trying to set the initial state or are you trying to update the state with what was fetched? Based on the code I'm assuming you are hitting an error something like "cannot access property rules of undefined..." because testData is initially an empty object {} so testData.recommendation is undefined when you try to access prevState.recommendation.rules to shallow copy the array. Pass the initial state value you want to the useState hook. Please [edit] to clarify the specific issue you have and want help with.

Hi @DrewReese, thanks for responding. I want to know how I can resolve this error    -->testData.recommendation is undefined.
Later, I want to follow similar approach to update my redux state as I tried I am getting same error for updating redux state. could you tell how can I resolve this.
I guess solution edit/provided  by Antonija Šimić will work.

Just define your initial testData state to have those nested properties defined, no need for the effect to set the initial state as this is a bit of an anti-pattern. That said... modern Redux is written using Redux-Toolkit which allows for writing mutable state updates, so the immutable state update pattern isn't really relevant.

Also, Antonija's solution looks like it will render loop when testData.recommendation.rules is truthy since that updates the state which triggers a rerender and runs the effect again.

@Drew Reese, could you provide your point with updated code. so that  it would be easy for me to undertsand your point.

It's still unclear to me what exactly your question is. Your initial state is an empty object and then you are trying to use a useEffect hook to iterate non-existent state while at the same time another useEffect hook is fetching some data and simply replacing the state. You appear to be indirectly asking about how to generally use/apply the Immutable Update pattern. Can you [edit] your post to clarify and focus on a single issue or question?

Initially, testData is an empty object {}. This can lead to issues when you try to update deeply nested properties (like recommendation.rules) because they may not exist in the initial state, since the object is empty. After fetching data from the API, you correctly set the state with the result. However, there could be a timing issue where the second useEffect runs BEFORE the data has been fetched, leading to errors when trying to access nested properties (that do not yet exist).
You must ensure that the update only happens after the state has been properly initialized.
Here is a modest proposition
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [testData, setTestData] = useState({});  // Initial empty state

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/recommendations");
        const result = await response.json(); 
        setTestData(result);  // Set state with fetched data
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Found error while fetching data: ${err}`);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);  // Run only once when the component mounts

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the data has been fetched and contains the expected structure
// here you can add your own transformers/validations
    if (testData.recommendation && Array.isArray(testData.recommendation.rules)) {
      setTestData(prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState, // spreading
          recommendation: {
            ...prevState.recommendation, // spreading
            rules: prevState.recommendation.rules.map(rule => {
              if (rule.scenario_name === "data_rule") {
                return {
                  ...rule, // spreading
                  passwhen: {
                    ...rule.passwhen, // spreading
                    STATE: "INDIA"  // Updating the STATE field
                  }
                };
              }
              return rule;
            })
          }
        };
      });
    }
  }, [testData]);  // <= Only run when testData is updated. This part is super important

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(testData, null, 2)}</pre> {/* Display the updated state */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

When updating a deeply nested state, you need to carefully handle the immutability by spreading the existing objects and arrays. I highly recommend these two articles:

https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/
https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

